# Desenvolvimento windows CE Cortex-A9

Tags: lazarus, windows-ce, cortex-a

Tenho um coletor Processador: Ti Cortex-A9 OMAP4430, desenvolvi uma alicação utilizando o lazarus 1.6.2, estou tentando compilar, estou recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Error: Illegal parameter: -CpCORTEXM3

[image]

Se colocar no Processador Alvo a opção "Padrão", eu consigo compilar mas a aplicação não funciona para esse tipo de processador.

Answer (score 0):

"-Cp" é  o código do parâmetro do Processador Alvo. O erro é que o parâmetro é ilegal. Isso quer dizer que o compilador do Lazarus infelizmente não é compatível diretamente com o seu processador. Eu digo "diretamente" pois você consegue compilar com outros processadores alvo definidos, mas não com o seu.